# Jupyter/ipywidgets sorting dataframe on two levels

Tags: pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

Google has failed me, so hopefully someone can help me out.

I'm working with a Jupyter notebook.  I have a dataframe and am trying to setup interactive widgets to sort that dataframe.

The dataframe is about athletes.  I am trying to sort the dataframe by athlete name, and then sort that by the disciplines that athlete competes in.  So, I want to be able to select "Jon", and then after selecting "Jon", I want to be able to narrow down the data returned so that I can look at "Jon's" Triple Jump (and only triple jump) if selected, but be able to switch over to look at "Jon's" Long Jump results if I select that.

```
data = pd.read_csv("Athlete Rank Moments.csv", encoding = "latin-1", usecols = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 16], 
               parse_dates = True, infer_datetime_format = True)
data["RankDate"] = pd.to_datetime(data["RankDate"], errors="coerce")

items = ['All']+sorted(data["Person/Team"].unique().tolist())
discipline_items = ['All']+sorted(data["Discipline"].unique().tolist())


def view(x='', y=''):
    if x == 'All': return data
    return data[data['Person/Team','Discipline']==x]


w = widgets.Select(options=items)
z = widgets.Select(options = discipline_items)
v = interact(view, x=w, y=z)
display(v)
```

This code gives me two drop down menus, but the drop down menu for the "discipline_list" doesn't alter the data returned at all.  OBviously, this is because the view function doesn't do anything with it, but I don't know what to write in the view function to get the result I want.  ANy help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide a dummy version of the DataFrame? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by breaking up your `view` function into two separate functions. The first one filters the DataFrame based on "Person/Team" and returns the results. The second function calls the first getting the results then filters and displays the DataFrame based on "Discipline". Then you call interact on the second function. Like so;

```
def view_1(x=""):
    if x == 'All':
        return data
    else:
        return data[data['Person/Team']==x]

def view_2(x="", y=""):
    data_2 = view_1(x)
    if y == 'All':
        display(data_2)
    else:
        display(data_2[data_2["Discipline"]==y])

w = widgets.Select(options=items)
z = widgets.Select(options=discipline_items)
v = interact(view_2, x=w, y=z)
display(v)
```

I've tested similar functions on DataFrames that I'm working on with positive results but I can't guarantee that this will work for you because your question lacks a sample DataFrame. Anyways hope that helps!